# Implication symbol

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I'm looking for a good implication symbol. I understood I was supposed to use `\to`, but it's longer than `\land` and `\lor` and it kinda bugs me. Is it possible to type an arrow of the exact same length?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the "Comprehensive LaTeX Symbols List" (`texdoc symbols` will give it to you, or go to google), I see at least two possibilities: the `stmaryrd` package provides `\shortarrow`, and the `MnSymbol` package redefines `\rightarrow` to be shorter.  The second one, in particular, provides a *ton* of new math symbols, no doubt overwriting everything already in existence, so you may want to be wary.

Comment: Well, I'm using `MnSymbol` anyway (I have to use a different symbol which the package provides), yet the arrow still isn't short enough... Bummer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Logician: there is another answer on this topic: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14388/575.  To say the least, it is intimidating, but describes the analogous process of importing one symbol from `mathabx`.  In this way, you can get `\shortarrow` without using `stmaryrd` entirely.

Comment: @Logician: actually, the second answer (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14406/575, by egreg) is fairly comprehensible to me and, I think, requires changing only the last line of code.  One (you or I) will have to look through the source for `stmaryrd` to figure out what particular character code the `\shortarrow` symbol has in that font.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is `\implies`.  This is longer than the width of the standard `to`, but you can use `\scalebox` from [the `graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) to re-size this to be the same width:

[image]

Alternatively, you can also scale the `\to` to be the width of the `\land`:

[image]

### Note:

- To make the `\ScaledImplies` have the same size and spacing as the `\to`, I scaled `\Longrightarrow` (which is what the `\implies` symbol from the `amsmath` package is based on with some additional spacing).

### Further Enhancements:

- I used the `pgf` package for the math calculations. There is most likely a way to do the same computation without this package so this code could be optimized to not require the `pgf` package.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\@widthOfTo%
\newdimen\@widthOfLand%
\newdimen\@widthOfImplies%
\settowidth{\@widthOfTo}{$\to$}%
\settowidth{\@widthOfLand}{$\land$}%
\settowidth{\@widthOfImplies}{$\Longrightarrow$}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\@scaleFactorImplies}{\@widthOfTo/\@widthOfImplies}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\@scaleFactorTo}{\@widthOfLand/\@widthOfTo}%
\newcommand*{\ScaledImplies}{\mathrel{\raisebox{0.3ex}{\scalebox{\@scaleFactorImplies}{\ensuremath{\Longrightarrow}}}}}%
\newcommand*{\ScaledTo}{\mathbin{\raisebox{0.3ex}{\scalebox{\@scaleFactorTo}{\ensuremath{\to}}}}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  $a \to b$\par
  $a \ScaledImplies b$\par
  $a \implies b$\par

  \bigskip
  $a \land b$\par
  $a \ScaledTo b$\par
  $a \to b$\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Logician: Updated to provide a scaling of the `\to` to be the same width as the `\land`.

Answer (score 3):

there is a "short" double up-arrow in the cm extension font that can be rotated for this purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\implyarrow}{%
  \mathrel{\raisebox{1.3ex}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\mathhexbox37F}}}}
\begin{document}
$a \implyarrow b \Rightarrow c$\\
$a \land b$
\end{document}
```

yielding

[image: example of short up-arrow rotated to point to the right]

Comment: It's possible for the symbol to have the correct size in scriptstyle and scriptscriptstyle by adding a `\text` around the boxes: `\newcommand{\implyarrow}{\mathrel{\text{\raisebox{1.3ex}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\mathhexbox37F}}}}}`

Comment: @Philippe -- great observation.  i thought that would probably be the case, but didn't have time to test it.